# How do you say "the test was redone"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

I'm documenting some test cases and this sentence in particular bothered me:

> After the problem was fixed, the test was redone.

The thesaurus [wasn't helping much](http://thesaurus.com/browse/redone).

Can it be reworded in a better way?

Comment: Hmm, why do the vast majority of questions get downvoted here?

Comment: It's good that you made some research effort, but people may think that the answer is obvious, if you rephrase slightly.

Comment: David: I'd suggest you look harder at the question(s), not the downvote(s).

Comment: Off topic (request for writing advice).

Comment: As such, you don't *redo* a test, you only *repeat* it. "... the test was repeated."

Comment: Do you want us to reword it, or choose a word that isn't *redone*?

Comment: Why is the thesaurus entry not helpful? "*start over* 
Synonyms: *do over again, redecorate, redesign, remake, remodel, renovate, repeat, rethink, revamp, revise*" -- none of which suits here. *Redo* does **not** just mean *do one more time*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Redone* is clear and sufficient for speech or notes, but may appear unsophisticated in technical documentation. Consider rewording slightly:

> After the problem was fixed, the test was run again.

Also consider active voice, which is slightly less wordy:

> After fixing the problem, we ran the test again.

Comment: FYI, using overly simple words instead of better diction is called [Buffy Speak](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BuffySpeak) in some circles.

Answer (score 1):

A problem needed to be fixed prior to repeating the test.

Comment: It's not clear whether the questioner meant to imply a causal relationship; if so, this is a good answer.

Comment: @RoDaSm that's slightly changing the meaning of the phrase. I meant that the problem was fixed not that it needed to be fixed. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: Ah! Now you're getting closer to the gist of why questions get downvoted here. A related question would be, "Why do so many people post questions here asking for help with language, yet provide so little context in their question?" Had you elaborated more about **why** you were dissatisfied with _redone_, along with some of the thesaurus entries you linked to but didn't bother to mention, there's a good chance that downvote might have been an upvote instead. It's a bit hard to offer a "better" word when it's not entirely clear what's wrong with the first, other than you are "bothered" by it.

Comment: @J.R. Ok, I'll keep that in mind for the next question, thanks for telling me why.

Comment: @David: Not a problem. Incidentally, if you're really interested in learning more about asking questions that will be well-received by the community, I recommend checking out [this user's questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi?tab=questions). They are invariably a delight to read, ponder, and follow.